# Not able to get installed date and time of installed softwares in local machine using WMI and Registry

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, registry, wmi

I tried to get the installed softwares in local machine along with installed date with timestamp.
But i am getting only date like "20140225" using property InstallDate, we have one more property InstallDate2 but i am getting null value for this. I want to get the installed programs with date and time in c#.net.

Can anybody give the solution for this.

Thanks in advance.

My code using Registry:

```
                string uninstallKey = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall";
                    using (RegistryKey rk = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(uninstallKey))
                    {
                        foreach (string skName in rk.GetSubKeyNames())
                        {
                            using (RegistryKey sk = rk.OpenSubKey(skName))
                            {
                                // we have many attributes other than these which are useful.
                                Console.WriteLine(sk.GetValue("DisplayName") + "-   " + sk.GetValue("DisplayVersion") + "  -" + sk.GetValue("InstallDate") + "  -" + sk.GetValue("Publisher"));
                            }

                        }
                    }
                    Console.ReadLine();
```

And This is using WMI Code:

ManagementObjectCollection moReturn;

```
        ManagementObjectSearcher moSearch;

        moSearch = new ManagementObjectSearcher("Select * from Win32_Product");

        moReturn = moSearch.Get();
        foreach (ManagementObject mo in moReturn)
        {
            Library.WriteLogMessageList("Name: " + mo["Name"].ToString() + "Date:" + mo["InstallDate"].ToString() + "Caption: " + mo["Caption"].ToString() + "Description: " + mo["Description"].ToString());

            listPro.Add(new ListProgramProperties { Name = mo["Name"].ToString(), Caption = mo["Caption"].ToString(), Description = mo["Description"].ToString(), InstalledDate = mo["InstallDate"].ToString() });


          //  Console.WriteLine(mo["Name"].ToString()); //+ " || " +mo["InstallDate2"].ToString()
        }




    }
```

Comment: What format do you want the date in?

Comment: 2015-01-05 11:40 AM  like this with date and time.
But instead of this i am getting as 20150105 .

Answer (score 0):

This is probably what you need:

Replace 
`mo["InstallDate"].ToString()` with `mo["InstallDate"].ToString("yyyy-MM-dd h:mm tt")`

You can specify any of [these formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx)  as an argument in `ToString()`